# Pointers in functions and pointers in lists

Tags: c

When I was introduced to pointers, I was told that they are useful because they let us modify certain variables fed into functions that wouldn't normally be modifiable. For example:

```
void copy(int *p, int *s);  

int main(){
  int a = 4, b = 10, *p = &a, *s = &b;
  copy(p, s);
}

void copy(int *p, int *s){
  *s = *p;
  *p = 0;
}
```

So at the end of this, "b" is equal to "a", and "a" is equal to 0, even though "a" and "b" wouldn't normally be modifiable.

When talking about lists and, specifically, adding an element to a list, I can use a function like this:

```
struct list{
  int n;
  struct list *next;
}

struct list *first = NULL;

int main(){
   int n = 3;
   first = add_to_list(first, n);
}

struct list *add_to_list(struct list *first, int n){
  struct list *new_node;
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  if(new_node == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  new_node->value = n;
  new_node->next = first;
  return new_node;
}
```

What concerns me specifically is why the function can't simply return a type void, and instead of writing *"return new_node"*, I can't simply write *"first = new_node"*. Because first is a pointer, if I modify it anywhere in my program the original pointer should be modified too, just like it happened in the first example I made, right?

Also, bit of an unrelated question, but if I've got a function like this:

```
void first_to_n(int a[], int n){
  a[0] = n;
}
```

The first element of the original vector a, which lets say is declared in main, gets also modified, right? Because vectors can be considered as pointers

Comment: The important thing here that you need to learn is that arguments in C are passed by value, that is the value is copied. That of course goes for pointers as well, if you pass a variable that is a pointer to something, then what is copied is the pointer. To emulate pass by reference you need to pass a pointer to the variable, which for pointer variables becomes pointers to pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So let's say that I'm passing a pointer to a function as a variable. Inside the function, the pointer gets reassigned to point to another variable. Would the original pointer be modified too or would it still point to the old variable?

Comment: As a side note, don't  declare more than one variable on a single line. Use one line per declaration. It's clearer this way.

Comment: @FoxyIT `the pointer gets reassigned` - the copy of the pointer get's reassigned. So the original pointer will still _point_ to the same memory, as the value of the original pointer will not change. But if you modify the memory to where the pointer points, it can be modified by any pointer that _points_ to the same place.

Comment: @FoxyIT: parameters are always passed **by value** to functions in C. If the variable is a pointer, then the variable merely holds an address of a certain object in memory. So, the **value** of the address is again passed through the parameter. For any function parameter `x`, writing `x = something;` inside the function will have no effect on the original variable outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have something like the following code

```
void funcA(int x)
{
    x = 0;
}

void funcB(int *y)
{
    y = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int *b = &a;

    funcA(a);
    funcB(b);
}
```

What happens when `funcA` is called is that the *value* of `a` is copied into the separate variable `x` inside the function. When the call is being made there are two copies of the value `10` stored in to different places. When the assignment `x = 0` is done inside the function, only the local variable `x` is modified.

For `funcB` just the same happens. The *value* of the variable `b` is copied into the separate variable `y` in the function. That means there are two separate and distinct variable pointing to the same location. But once the assignment `y = NULL` is done, that's no longer true. The variable `y` is no longer pointing to the same location, but in the `main` function `b` is unmodifed since only a copy of the value was passed to the function.

---

If we now take a slightly different example

```
void func(int *x, int **y)
{
    *y = x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int *c = &a;  // Make c point to the variable a

    func(&b, &c);
}
```

After the function is called, then `c` does no longer point to `a`, it points to `b`. That's because for the second argument the value we pass is `&c` which is a pointer to the variable `c`. Inside the function we can then use the dereference operator to access what `y` is pointing to (which will be the variable `c` in the `main` function).

Comment: Why do you pass 'b' by value if func takes a pointer as a first argument?

Comment: @machine_1 Oops!

Answer (score 1):

> When I was introduced to pointers, I was told that they are useful because they let us modify certain variables fed into functions that wouldn't normally be modifiable.

Among other things, like creating non-trivial data structures and to avoid copies.

> Because first is a pointer, if I modify it anywhere in my program the original pointer should be modified too, just like it happened in the first example I made, right?

`first` (the parameter) is a copy of `first` (the global). Therefore, `first = new_node` would only modify your pointer, not the global one.

This is more clear in your first example:

```
void copy(int *p, int *s){
  *s = *p;
  *p = 0;
}
```

If you were doing `p = 0;`, for instance, you would only modify the pointer, not the value pointed to.

> The first element of the original vector a, which lets say is declared in main, gets also modified, right? Because vectors can be considered as pointers

That is not a "vector" (array), it is a pointer even if it looks like an array. It is a big gotcha of C.

But, indeed, `a[0] = 0;` is modifying the first value (in `main`) pointed by the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> What concerns me specifically is why the function can't simply return
>   a type void, and instead of writing "return new_node", I can't simply
>   write "first = new_node".

As the other answers explain, you can't due to `first` being a 'copy' of the pointer outside the function.  If however you were to instead change the function such that you passed a 'pointer to the pointer' rather that just the 'pointer', then you could change the external value, which is what's going on the in the 'copy' function.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a pointer to a literal string.
The pointer is pass to `modifypointer()` where it is modified to point to another literal string. The new literal string is printed in the function, but `main()` still prints the original.
The pointer is passed as a pointer to itself in `modifypointertopointer()` where it is dereferenced to point to another literal string. Now the function prints the new literal string and `main()` also prints the new literal string.
In your last example, `first = new_node;` could be used except the function declares a shadow variable `first` and the global `first` is no longer in the scope of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void modifypointer( char *mod) {
    mod = "modify pointer";
    printf ( "%s\n", mod);
}

void modifypointertopointer( char **ptrmod) {
    *ptrmod = "modify pointer to pointer";
    printf ( "%s\n", *ptrmod);
}

int main( void) {
    char *text = "original";
    printf ( "%s\n", text);
    modifypointer ( text);
    printf ( "%s\n", text);
    modifypointertopointer ( &text);
    printf ( "%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```